# How to make Emacs C source directory permanent?

Tags: emacs

I'm new to Emacs and I'm just learning how to use it. I know how to set my "Emacs C Source dir" but I don't know how to make this change permanent. I guess I have to set it in my .emacs file but I don't know what is the command for it. Can someone help?

Comment: Do you mean the directory for the Emacs C sources themselves?  How are you setting it now?

Comment: @NicholasRiley: Yes, I searched for a command description like other-buffer using apropos and then I click on the `C source code' link and then when asked for the "Emacs C Source dir" I set it. How can I make this permanent?

Comment: I have to say I didn't bother poking around the Emacs C sources for almost a decade after I started using Emacs, so good for you :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Ordinarily most user-settable variables can be edited with Customize, but for some reason the `source-directory` variable isn't one of them.

You will need to edit your `~/.emacs` file to include a line such as:

```
(setq source-directory "/path/to/emacs/source/dir")
```

Do not include the trailing `src` directory; it will be added automatically.  Then exit and restart Emacs.

Note that setting this after Emacs is running may have no effect because it's only read when `find-func.el` is loaded.  You can set `find-function-C-source-directory` instead (with the `/src`), but that can get overwritten.  It's better just to `(setq source-directory ...)` at startup, as above.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a decent [locate](https://www.linfo.org/locate.html)-style shell-command, this saves you having to remember the path exactly. It should thus still work in your `~/.emacs.d/init.el` if you upgrade to a newer version, as long as you still have the [sources](http://gnu.askapache.com/emacs/).

```
(setq source-directory
      (file-name-directory
       (shell-command-to-string
    (concat "locate --limit 1 emacs-" emacs-version "/src"))))
```