# What is the correct path to the C source files for Emacs?

Tags: emacs

So, way back in January, I went here:

http://emacsformacosx.com/

I downloaded Emacs and have been using it on my Mac and I like it. I've started trying to get into Elisp programming. To learn more, I'd like to look up some functions. So for instance I do:

```
C-h f
```

and then type "scroll-down"

This gives me the following text:

```
>scroll-down is an interactive built-in function in `window.c'.
>
>It is bound to <kp-prior>, <prior>, C-1, C-x C-1, M-v.
>
>(scroll-down &optional ARG)
>
>Scroll text of selected window down ARG lines.
>If ARG is omitted or nil, scroll down by a near full screen.
>A near full screen is `next-screen-context-lines' less than a full screen.
>Negative ARG means scroll upward.
>If ARG is the atom `-', scroll upward by nearly full screen.
>When calling from a program, supply as argument a number, nil, or `-'.
```

And the text "window.c" is a link. So I click on the link and I get:

```
find-function-C-source: The C source file window.c is not available
```

I'm getting this error a lot while doing a lot of different things. Where do I find the right path, and how do I tell Emacs what that path is?

I did just recently install some ELPA packages, so maybe one of them is causing some chaos?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Emacs C source directory permanent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595317/how-to-make-emacs-c-source-directory-permanent)

Answer (score 6):

The variable `source-directory` will point to the location where the C sources are. If you have a separately downloaded copy, you'll have to point this variable to that directory.

Comment: If I put this: (source-directory) in an empty buffer, and then I run eval-buffer, I get: "Symbol's function definition is void: source-directory"

Comment: Skip the parentheses. It's a variable. Not a function. Try `C-h v source-directory RET`.

Comment: It's really important to set the variable early. In my setup, I set it in my `early-init.el` and it works.

Answer (score 3):

Most packagers don't include the sources, or split them off into a separate package. Install the sources (and maybe tweak an init script to tell Emacs where you put them, if it's not the default location. The pertinent variable is `find-function-C-source-directory`).

Comment: If I put this in an empty buffer: (find-function-C-source-directory) and then run eval-buffer I get: " Symbol's function definition is void: find-function-C-source-directory"

Comment: Remove the parens to eval the variable.  With the parentheses, you are attempting to access a function of that name, which indeed does not exist.  More usefully, use `C-h v` to examine a variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595317/how-to-make-emacs-c-source-directory-permanent advises to prefer `source-directory` over `find-function-C-source-directory` but it's not immediately apparent to me why.

Comment: Okay, thanks, Found this finally. Does anyone know where the source files traditionally go? They have been placed in an odd location in my harddrive, I'd like to move them somewhere standard, if only I knew that was.

Comment: For a traditional Unix system, something like `/usr/local/src/emacs/emacs23.4/src` would seem to make sense (where the label `emacs23.4` is the version you are using).

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I can now do "C-h f" and drill down to the actual source files.

Comment: Please mark one of the answers as accepted so that this question does not come up as requiring an answer still.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't manually build Emacs from the source code and patch the C source code, value of `source-directory` or `find-function-C-source-directory` would be wrong.

You can manually download Emacs source code, unpack it somewhere and set above two variables accordingly like following

```lisp
(setq source-directory "/path/to/your-emacs-repo")

;; OR

(setq find-function-C-source-directory "/path/to/your-emacs-repo/src")
```

GNU Emacs source code and development is hosted on [savannah.gnu.org](http://savannah.gnu.org/projects/emacs/). You can find all the tags [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/refs/tags) and download the one that matches your `M-x emacs-version`.